# Is there StartsWith or Contains in t sql with variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to detect if the server is running Express Edition.

I have the following t sql.

```
DECLARE @edition varchar(50); 
set @edition = cast((select SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')) as varchar)

print @edition
```

In my instance, `@edition = Express Edition (64-bit)`

How can I do the following? (C# inspired).

```
DECLARE @isExpress bit;
set @isExpress = @edition.StartsWith('Express Edition');
```

Answer (score 179, accepted):

**StartsWith**

```
a) left(@edition, 15) = 'Express Edition'
b) charindex('Express Edition', @edition) = 1
```

**Contains**

```
charindex('Express Edition', @edition) >= 1
```

**Examples**

[`left`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql) function

```
set @isExpress = case when left(@edition, 15) = 'Express Edition' then 1 else 0 end
```

[`iif`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) function (starting with SQL Server 2012)

```
set @isExpress = iif(left(@edition, 15) = 'Express Edition', 1, 0);
```

[`charindex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) function

```
set @isExpress = iif(charindex('Express Edition', @edition) = 1, 1, 0);
```

Comment: Note that internally these work differently, especially w.r.t. performance and its use of indexes. For example, a query using  `colName LIKE 'prefix%'` will be very fast when `colName` is indexed, but `colName LIKE '%substring%'` or `colName LIKE '%suffix'` will be slow because SQL Server does not create suffix-trees when indexing text. Similarly using `LEFT` with a column will also be slow because those queries are not SARGable. SARGability is important: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean

Comment: I would recommend to test the LIKE 'x%' method mentioned below. In some cases it is much faster

Comment: Logically I would avoid charindex.. I would assume char index will search the entire string to find the first chacacter, then check for the second character etc. Eg it won't realize that you are not interesed if the string starts at position 2 or greater

Answer (score 77):

It seems like what you want is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx.

In your example it would be (starts with):

```
set @isExpress = (CharIndex('Express Edition', @edition) = 1)
```

Or contains

```
set @isExpress = (CharIndex('Express Edition', @edition) >= 1)
```

Comment: Why not use LIKE `Express Edition%` ? Also, doesn't your solution return true of "Express Edition" is anywhere in the string? So it's more specifically just a "Contains" sort of way of doing it

Comment: @mmcrae While using the like version below would be fine this was the first way that came to mind and looks most like what the OP had. Also, the first expression will only return true if the variable starts with (charindex returns 1) the given argument. The second expression is a contains as it will return true if the argument is found anywhere in the string (charindex returns 1 or greater).

Answer (score 64):

I would use

```
like 'Express Edition%'
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @edition varchar(50); 
set @edition = cast((select SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')) as varchar)

DECLARE @isExpress bit
if @edition like 'Express Edition%'
    set @isExpress = 1;
else
    set @isExpress = 0;

print @isExpress
```

Comment: If you read the question, it is not a query. Try my example with your answer and then please update your answer showing it works.

Comment: You can use like in if-statements in t-sql. This is why I use like. I don't see why you want to give me minus points for that but why not.

Comment: This should be the preferred way; it's more elegant, less verbose and "SQL aligned": as it uses the standard SQL LIKE operator, I should not need to read the documentation to understand it!

Comment: Beware of this when there might be special characters in the like-string, e. g. '['. One might have to add escaping, but even then it seems to behave differently in different circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the explanation of what you can do while filtering the data - in the end, you just pass the variable in a place where you need it.

```
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%'
--Finds any values that start with "a"

WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%a'
--Finds any values that end with "a"

WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%'
--Finds any values that have "or" in any position

WHERE CustomerName LIKE '_r%'
--Finds any values that have "r" in the second position

WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a__%'
--Finds any values that start with "a" and are at least 3 characters in length

WHERE ContactName LIKE 'a%o'
--Finds any values that start with "a" and ends with "o"

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE upper(my_column) LIKE 'SEARCHED%';
--Starts with, case insensitive 

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE upper(my_column) LIKE '%SEARCHED';
--Ends with, case insensitive

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE upper(my_column) LIKE '%SEARCHED%';
--Contains, case insensitive
```