# Entity Framework: StartsWith to SQL

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, linq-to-sql, sql-like, startswith

Entity Framework (Core 2.0.2) translate

```
.Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith(term))
```

into this SQL

```
([t].[Name] LIKE @__term_1 + N''%'' AND (LEFT([t].[Name], LEN(@__term_1)) = @__term_1))
```

Don't the left and right parts (of this SQL splitted by `AND`) do the same and can't each of them be used independently?

Comment: What version of Entity Framework?

Comment: @TiesonT. _Entity Framework Core 2.0.2_, I will add it to the question.

Comment: Why do you ask here? EF-core has an excellent support forum. Questions about third-party implementations are always opinion-based because everybody has to guess.

Comment: The RHS (after the `AND`) seems incomplete?

Comment: @GertArnold Is there a question on this site that isn't about third party implementations?

Comment: @NetMage What I mean is: questions like "why did product X implement feature Y that way?" We can only say, because....

Comment: The only thing I'm interested in is whether it makes sense to use both parts of the expression and whether using one of them wouldn't be enough. I will change the beginning of the question so as not to cause unnecessary disputes.

Comment: @NetMage you're right, I missed one closing parenthesis, already fixed. The full version of that SQL contains additional OR-part, but it does not raise any question: _OR (@__term_1 = N'''')_

Comment: Still, if you ask at the EF-core support site you'll get an answer from people that build the stuff. What can we say? Yes, it's useless, EF6 doesn't do this. By the way, you also forgot an equality in the second predicate.

Comment: @GertArnold Thank for the correction! Ok, I'll ask there. But which part (`LIKE` or `LEFT+LEN`) is preferable for using alone? I mean which one is more effective?

Comment: I don't know. That would require benchmarking. Generally, in view of sargeability, it's not recommended to convert a column value before filtering (which `LEFT` does). OTOH, `LIKE` doesn't perform too well either. One consolation: the predicates will shortcut, so if the `LIKE` is very selective not many `LEFT` comparisons will be executed.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll also consider these examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493844/is-there-startswith-or-contains-in-t-sql-with-variables

Comment: Is the translation provider dependent? If so, I would assume the database in question has been tested to verify the `LIKE` is worth it to reduce the testing needed.

Comment: @NetMage It's used with MS SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following EF Core issue tracker thread could shed some light on why it is implemented this way - [Query: Improve translation of String's StartsWith, EndsWith and Contains #474](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/474) . Here are some important excerpts:

> Linq translation for methods `Contains`, `EndsWith` and `StartsWith` that we have in the Relational package uses `LIKE` operator, which may return incorrect results if the value parameter (what we are searching for) contains wildcard characters, e.g. '%' or '_'.

and then

> In general for cases in which `LIKE` doesn't work well we can fall back to alternative translations that don't rely on `LIKE`, e.g. for `String.StartsWith()`:
>
> `var underscoreAThings = Things.Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith(t.Prefix));`
>
> `SELECT * FROM Things WHERE CHARINDEX(Prefix, Name) = 1 OR Prefix='';`
>
> Note that `CHARINDEX()` won't match an empty string but `String.StartsWith("")` always return true, that's why we add the Prefix ='' condition.
>   The main disadvantage of this translation is that it is not sargable. That can be addressed with a hybrid translation, e.g.:
>
> `SELECT * FROM Things WHERE Name LIKE Prefix+'%' AND (CHARINDEX(Prefix, Name) = 1 OR Prefix = '');`

Shortly, with the current translation they address SQL query sargeability as well as the CLR `string.StartsWith` method compatibility. In different phases of the EF Core development they used only first or only second approach, and finally get to this hybrid approach.

Comment: Well spotted! Sometimes I think they should add a comment to the generated SQL code. Would have been really helpful in this case.

Comment: It's a really clever solution, I liked it and learnt something new about SQL. 
Although it's not still clear to me why the empty string can't be filtered by the client.

Comment: @Sergey I think they do that in the final implementation (using static column nullability and parameter value analysis). The thread just shows their process of thinking and addressing the potential issues/use cases. The important is, `LIKE` is used to quickly filter the result using index (when available), but potentially producing false positives. Then the right part is implementing the actual filter. One of the ORM benefits is that it can do such optimizations rather than doing them by hand writing the SQL query.

Comment: _[LIKE is used to quickly filter the result using index (when available)]_ thank you, Ivan, I noticed that, in particular, only if the string comparison starts from the beginning, iow it's useful only for _StartWith_.